# Controlling two slider's components with same buttons/controllers in owlcarousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I have two owl carousel. And one is over the other. One is image with some content and other is only content. And the both slider needs to change together.

This the code below for content slider

```
                        <div id="owkey-content-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        <div class="item">

                            <div class="slider-content">
                                <h4>WE CREATE</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="slider-content">
                                <h4>WE BUILD</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="slider-content">
                                <h4>WE OFFER</h4>
                            </div>                       
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="slider-content">
                                <h4>WE DELIVER</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the codes for image slider

```
        <div class="header-bg-image-slide">
        <div id="owkey-bg-slider" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/owkey-slider-2.jpg">
                <div class="number-item">01</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/owkey-slider.jpg">
                <div class="number-item">02</div>

            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/shutterstock_327808505.jpg">
                <div class="number-item">03</div>                       
            </div>
            <div class="item">

                <img src="img/owkey-head.png">
                <div class="number-item">04</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And they are initialized in the same conditions/parameters. They are changing together. But, when button was clicked those buttons are for the image slider and that doesn't change the other slider's contents certainly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var owl = $("#owkey-bg-slider, #owkey-content-slider");
        owl.owlCarousel({
            navigation : true,
            navigationText: ["<i class=\"fa fa-angle-up\">","<i class=\"fa fa-angle-down\">"],
            singleItem : true,
            transitionStyle : "fade",
            autoPlay: true,
            touchDrag: false,
            mouseDrag: false
        });
    })
</script>
```

And I think experienced owl carousel user can help me in this.

There are solution for this problem in here that is for any other kind of slider but not for owl carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flickity Slider](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/), it's a much better slider plugin.